# How to edit the parent Form when a child Form is active?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I open a child Form, I need the parent Form to remain accessible.
For example, I could type in a text field.

Comment: And open it using `Form.Show()`, not `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Three solid options (each with own con/pro): 1) MDI 2) multiple modeless forms 3) user controls as children.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **user controls** for this type of functionality.

by using user controls you can use single form with multiple user controls at a time.

to know how user control works:
[watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLfzH4xOVqo)

**OR**

by using show(), Hide(), BringToFront() and SendToBack() you can do but it will add complexity to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can open it by Show, but maybe set original form as owner, so that it does not move to background.

```
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Owner = this;
        f2.Show();
```

Comment: Better: `f2.Show(this);`. It sets the owner in a proper way.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't have reputation to vote you up